# Trying to create a project in a sub folder gives "<projectname> overlaps the location of another project" error

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace, subdirectory

I'm new to Java / Eclipse.

I've opened eclipse and set the workspace to a folder named MyBook.

Next I want to create a bunch of projects in subfolders of the workspace.  I want to create a project in MyBook\Ch-01\MyExampleApple and then create a project in MyBook\Ch-02\MyExampleBanana, etc...  When I try to create the first project I get the error "MyBook\Ch-01\MyExampleApple overlaps the location of another project Ch-01".

How do I create a new project in a sub folder of the workspace?  Do I need to change the workspace to match the subfolder before I can create the project?

[The product I currently use doesn't have the concept of a workspace, and you always specify the full location of any new project.  Please let me know what the correct procedure is for this in Eclipse.]

Comment: you can't create a project inside a project !

Comment: Sure - I want to create a project inside a subfolder in a workspace - can I do that?  Is a workspace a project?  Is a subfolder a project?  I'm just trying to learn how Eclipse views things.  So if I want to create my project in the folder MyBook\Ch-01\MyProject how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

1-Take for workspace "MyBook"
2-In eclipse, create a "Java project" ch-01.
3-right click on ch-01 , new, project "MyExampleApple"
for each folder like ch-01 do number 2 and 3.
:)

This will create a subFolder in your Workspace and a project inside this subFolder.

workspace  subfolder   project
MyBook    \Ch-01      \MyExampleApple

:D